# Bind all Descriptions of an enum to a combobox

Tags: vb.net, enums, combobox

How can I bind the formatted string descriptions of an enumeration to a combobox? I want the combobox to show the descriptions, not the enum.

I have an enum like this:

```
Public Enum Sandwiches
<ComponentModel.Description("Ham Sandwich")> HamSandwich
<ComponentModel.Description("Reuben")> Reuben
<ComponentModel.Description("Po’ Boy")> PoBoy
<ComponentModel.Description("Grilled Cheese")> GrilledCheese
End Enum
```

I can use this function to convert the selected item back to an enum, after the description string has already been bound to a combobox:

```
        Public Function GetEnumFromDescriptionAttribute(Of T)(description As String) As T
        Dim type As Type = GetType(T)
        If Not type.IsEnum Then
            Throw New InvalidOperationException()
        End If
        For Each fi As Reflection.FieldInfo In type.GetFields()
            Dim descriptionAttribute As ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute = TryCast(Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(fi, GetType(ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute)), ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute)
            If descriptionAttribute IsNot Nothing Then
                If descriptionAttribute.Description <> description Then
                    Continue For
                End If
                Return DirectCast(fi.GetValue(Nothing), T)
            End If
            If fi.Name <> description Then
                Continue For
            End If
            Return DirectCast(fi.GetValue(Nothing), T)
        Next
        Return Nothing
    End Function
```

But I cannot find a clean way to bind all of the enumerations to the combobox. I know that an often sugested solution is to convert the enums and enum descriptions to a dictionary, and then set those as the cbo DisplayMember and ValueMember. But I cannot figure out how to actually do that.,

I've ready through dozens of partial solutions on how to do this; The problem is that they are all written in C#, use implicit conversion with Option Strict turned OFF, and don't show the full implementation. So it's impossible for me to translate any of the solutions into .NET, since I have no idea what type variables have been defined as.

Comment: [This](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?552547) should be of interest to you.

Comment: I have added an answer that uses the code from the link above.

Comment: OT, `Sandwiches` is the wrong name for that `Enum`. It should be `Sandwich`. You should pluralise the name of an `Enum` if and only if it has the `Flags` attribute applied. You use that attribute if you want to be able to create composite values, hence the pluralisation. If you only ever use a single value at a time then you use a singular name.

Comment: `dim attr = GetType(Sandwiches).GetFields().Select(Function(f) f.GetCustomAttribute(Of DescriptionAttribute)?.Description).ToArray()`. It's a sequential enumeration, `value = SelectedIndex`. Remove the first null value, eventually.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, I've apparently been naming my Enums wrong for a long time then. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a class that I wrote some time ago to represent an `Enum` value and its description:

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Reflection
 
''' <summary>
''' Contains an enumerated constant value and a friendly description of that value, if one exists.
''' </summary>
''' <typeparam name="T">
''' The enumerated type of the value.
''' </typeparam>
Public Class EnumDescriptor(Of T)
 
    ''' <summary>
    ''' The friendly description of the value.
    ''' </summary>
    Private _description As String
    ''' <summary>
    ''' The enumerated constant value.
    ''' </summary>
    Private _value As T
 
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets the friendly description of the value.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value>
    ''' A <b>String</b> containing the value's Description attribute value if one exists; otherwise, the value name.
    ''' </value>
    Public ReadOnly Property Description() As String
        Get
            Return Me._description
        End Get
    End Property
 
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets the enumerated constant value.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value>
    ''' An enumerated constant of the <b>EnumDescriptor's</b> generic parameter type.
    ''' </value>
    Public ReadOnly Property Value() As T
        Get
            Return Me._value
        End Get
    End Property
 
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Creates a new instance of the <b>EnumDescriptor</b> class.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="value">
    ''' The value to provide a description for.
    ''' </param>
    Public Sub New(ByVal value As T)
        Me._value = value
 
        'Get the Description attribute.
        Dim field As FieldInfo = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString())
        Dim attributes As DescriptionAttribute() = DirectCast(field.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(DescriptionAttribute), _
                                                                                        False),  _
                                                              DescriptionAttribute())
 
        'Use the Description attribte if one exists, otherwise use the value itself as the description.
        Me._description = If(attributes.Length = 0, _
                             value.ToString(), _
                             attributes(0).Description)
    End Sub
 
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Overridden.  Creates a string representation of the object.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns>
    ''' The friendly description of the value.
    ''' </returns>
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Me.Description
    End Function
 
End Class
```

Here's a simplified version I just wrote:

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Reflection

Public Class EnumDescriptor(Of T)

    Public ReadOnly Property Description As String

    Public ReadOnly Property Value As T

    Public Sub New(value As T)
        Me.Value = value

        'Get the Description attribute.
        Dim field = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString())
        Dim attributes = DirectCast(field.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(DescriptionAttribute), False), DescriptionAttribute())

        'Use the Description attribute if one exists, otherwise use the value itself as the description.
        Description = If(attributes.Length = 0, value.ToString(), attributes(0).Description)
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Description
    End Function

End Class
```

Here's another class that can be used to store an instance of the previous class for each value in an `Enum`:

```vb
''' <summary>
''' A collection of EnumDescriptors for an enumerated type.
''' </summary>
''' <typeparam name="T">
''' The type of the enumeration for which the EnumDescriptors are created.
''' </typeparam>
Public Class EnumDescriptorCollection(Of T)
    Inherits ObjectModel.Collection(Of EnumDescriptor(Of T))
 
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Creates a new instance of the <b>EnumDescriptorCollection</b> class.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub New()
        'Populate the collection with an EnumDescriptor for each enumerated value.
        For Each value As T In [Enum].GetValues(GetType(T))
            Items.Add(New EnumDescriptor(Of T)(value))
        Next
    End Sub
 
End Class
```

Here's some example usage that binds a instance of the collection class to a `ComboBox`:

```vb
Public Class Form1
 
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        With ComboBox1
            .DisplayMember = "Description"
            .ValueMember = "Value"
            .DataSource = New EnumDescriptorCollection(Of Sandwiches)
        End With
    End Sub
 
    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        MessageBox.Show(ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString(), ComboBox1.Text)
    End Sub
 
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your goal is override the string representation of a Enum value.  The base representation displays Enum's name, where-as you want to display the Enum's Description attribute.

Assuming that this is a WinForm's combobox, the standard way would be to decorate the Enum with a custom [TypeConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter) and override the `ConvertTo` method.  Using the [EnumConverter Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.enumconverter) and the basis for the custom converter minimizes the required code.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.Reflection

Public Class EnumDescriptionConverter(Of T As {Structure, IConvertible}) : Inherits EnumConverter

  Private enumDescriptions As New Dictionary(Of T, String)

  Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New(GetType(T))
    ' Since the ability to add an Enum constraint to the generic type does not exist in VB.
    ' this check is to ensure that it is an Enum.
    ' Note that normally, throwing an exception in a constructor is considered bad form, but
    ' there is no other option
    If GetType(T).IsEnum Then
      LoadEnumDescriptions()
    Else
      Throw New ArgumentException($"{GetType(T).Name} is not an Enum")
    End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub LoadEnumDescriptions()
    ' An Enum type comprises static (Shared) fields that represent the defined enum values and
    ' an instance field that holds thae actual value. so only retrieve the static fields
    ' to get the defined (named) enum members.
    For Each fi As FieldInfo In GetType(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Static)
      Dim description As String
      Dim descAttrib As DescriptionAttribute = fi.GetCustomAttribute(Of DescriptionAttribute)
      If descAttrib Is Nothing Then
        ' no description attribute so use the defined name
        description = fi.Name
      Else
        description = descAttrib.Description
      End If
      enumDescriptions.Add(CType(fi.GetValue(Nothing), T), description)
    Next
  End Sub

  Public Overrides Function ConvertTo(context As ITypeDescriptorContext, culture As CultureInfo, value As Object, destinationType As Type) As Object
    Dim ret As Object

    ' the purpose of this converter is to provide an enum's description attribute as the string representation
    ' instead of the field name as provided by the standard implemention.
    If destinationType Is GetType(String) AndAlso value IsNot Nothing Then
      Dim enumValue As T = DirectCast(value, T)
      If enumDescriptions.ContainsKey(enumValue) Then
        ret = enumDescriptions(enumValue)
      Else
        ret = enumValue.ToString(Nothing)
      End If
    Else
      ret = MyBase.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType)
    End If
    Return ret
  End Function
End Class
```

Modify your Enum definition to use this custom converter.

```
<TypeConverter(GetType(EnumDescriptionConverter(Of Sandwiches)))>
Public Enum Sandwiches
  <ComponentModel.Description("Ham Sandwich")> HamSandwich
  <ComponentModel.Description("Reuben")> Reuben
  <ComponentModel.Description("Po’ Boy")> PoBoy
  <ComponentModel.Description("Grilled Cheese")> GrilledCheese
End Enum
```

Now all you need to do is load the `ComboBox.Items` with Enum values.

```
ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(System.Enum.GetValues(GetType(Sandwiches)).Cast(Of Object).ToArray())
```

[image]

Use the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` to retrieve the selected value.